# Hide Paired Bluetooth Devices

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am creating an Android application that interacts with BLE device. Is there a way to hide the paired device to prevent it from showing in the paired devices list of Android System?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. But if you don't pair, it won't show up...